# Generate password in bash store in variable

Tags: bash

I am currently writing a script for automating setting up a new server with ftp and apache, but I don't wanna write in what password they should use, so i wanted to generate it with the current line.

```
< /dev/urandom tr -dc _A-Z-a-z-0-9 | head -c12
```

however it does not seem to work when i put it inside a variable:

```
PASSGEN="< /dev/urandom tr -dc _A-Z-a-z-0-9 | head -c12"
FTPPASS=$(eval $PASSGEN)
DBPASS=$(eval $PASSGEN)
echo $FTPPASS
```

if i change the if PASSGEN string is date is works fine. Is there somehting i have missed completly?

Comment: As an aside: the operand to pass to `tr` should be `'_A-Za-z0-9-'` - no need to separate the ranges with `-`: place them right next to each other. `-` at the _end_ ensures that it cannot be mistaken for part of a range.

Comment: alright chears, yeah i was wondering that, but i just copied what i found on the web for generation

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are missing a `$` in front of the variable name (`$PASSGEN`), as you are wanting the variable expansion first:

```
FTPPASS=$(eval "$PASSGEN")
```

Also using all-uppercase variable name is not a good idea for user defined variables as those are typically used for environment variables. Also saving the password in a variable might not be a good idea depending on your environment.

---

**EDIT:**

I suggest you use command substitution `$()` instead, no need for `eval`:

```
$ PASSGEN=$(</dev/urandom tr -dc _A-Z-a-z-0-9 | head -c12)

$ echo $PASSGEN
zT52YgWXoXcW
```

Comment: sorry that was misstype in the post could not copy from my putty client

Comment: @HenrikBøgelundLavstsen It is working perfectly for me otherwise.

Comment: You are right works now misstyped the varible, whoops

Comment: @HenrikBøgelundLavstsen Check my edits, you should use command substitution.

Answer (score 1):

You are using a variable when you should be using a function.

```
passgen () {
  < /dev/urandom tr -dc _A-Z-a-z-0-9 | head -c12
}

ftp_pass=$(passgen)
db_pass=$(passgen)
echo "$ftp_pass"
echo "$db_pass"
```